# Floating Action Button

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, вот код активности:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#e0e6e8">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="e-mail*"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:text="Введите ваш E-mail"
        android:textColor="#c5c0c0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Адрес"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:text="Адрес"
        android:textColor="#c5c0c0"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Коммент"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:text="Коммент"
        android:textColor="#c5c0c0"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Категория"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_send"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_camera_enhance_black_48dp"
            android:background="#e0e6e8"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imgPreview" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Как мне добавить FAB так, что бы он был всегда в правом нижнем углу(при скроллинге)??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уточню ответ выше, видимо вы помещаете FAB внутрь ScrollView. Вынесите его "наружу" тогда при скроллинге она не будет скролиться :)

Схематично разметка будет выглядеть как то так:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView>
         ...
    </ScrollView>
    <FloatingActionButton>
         ...
    </FloatingActionButton>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. У вас здесь нет скроллинга
2. Использовать [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html?hl=ru)

Comment: Все это еще в ScrolView